# Prestashop backoffice css error

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

While migrating a multistore prestashop to a new domain.The prestashop front-office is working fine but back-office is getting css error. I attached my image link. 
Link:   https://s21.postimg.org/88hjk9m07/prestashop_1_5_back_office.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to empty your browser cache completly or change browser.
You should empty Prestashop cache too at menu Preferences -> Performance.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue of a wrong domain name in PrestaShop database. Ensure that in ps_shop_url database table, physical_URI value has a trailing slash.